# Using MySQL for storing books

Tags: mysql, text

I have a question.

Lasts week I have discussing with my collegians about stor place for big text, for example book text in my web project.

Generally all divided into two opinions:

1. Storing in DB (Mysql in my case)
2. Storing into table link to file or using directory structure named with Primary Key of book record.

Using PHP 7.1, Yii2 FW

All book (text) will be views in web page, with pagination.

I need your professional opinion about this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have fixed pages, then MySQL seems a good choice, so you can store each page of text under the page number of that text. Good for quick random lookups.

```
CREATE TABLE book (
    book_id  INT NOT NULL,
    page_no  INT NOT NULL,
    content  TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

Use an index on the `book_id` plus `page_number` for quick lookups

```
INDEX book_page (book_id, page_no)
```

If you used simple text files, you'd need to load the entire file only to access one single page.